# Replace and add rows to an old dataframe based on new dataframe and index using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to merge two dataframes replacing some rows based on string indexes and adding the new rows (new indexes). I'm curious about some kind of standard or **efficient** way to do it.

```
# Example: "A" and "B" are columns and "idx" is the index
# Input
# df1

idx  A  B  
a   1  1
b   2  2
c   3  3


# df2
idx  A   B      
a   -1  -1
b   -2  -2
d  -10 -10
f  -20 -20

# process
merged_df = replace_and_add(old_df=df_1, new_df=df_2)

# Output
# new_df      
idx  A   B      
a   -1  -1
b   -2  -2
c    3   3
d  -10 -10
f  -20 -20
```

Comment: `df2` and `merge_df` are the same and `df1` is a subset of `df2` Maybe, you should modify your example?

Comment: I updated the example, it was a wrong copy-paste

Comment: `idx` is a column or the index of the dataframe?

Comment: @Corralien it is the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reindex` your first dataframe with the second one then `update` values. It's an efficient way to avoid to create a temporary dataframe:

```
df1 = df1.reindex(df1.index.union(df2.index))
df1.update(df2)
print(df1)

# Output:
        A     B
idx            
a    -1.0  -1.0
b    -2.0  -2.0
c     3.0   3.0
d   -10.0 -10.0
f   -20.0 -20.0
```

The downside is the dtype which is now float64 instead of int64.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a concatenation of dataframes, without replication (union distinct). In pandas, you could:

```
df = pd.concat( [old_df, new_df] ).drop_duplicates()
```